# Using a label element to display an input with inner label - Input width exceeds label in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm trying to put a span inside of a text input to prefix it with the "$" character, to represent a dollar amount.

To do this, I'm using a label element containing the "$" span along with the actual input, which is set to 100% width. The label element is styled to look like a text box.

This works fine in Chrome and IE, however in Firefox it seems that setting 100% width on the input does not take the span into consideration, and therefore extends past the actual label element's boundaries:

[image: screenshot of issue in Firefox]

Code Example:

```css
.container { width: 400px; }
.w70 { width: 70px; }

.input-with-label {
   border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   background-color: #fff;
}

.input-with-label.-dollar-amount > input[type='text'] {
   text-align: right;
   font-weight: 600;
   
}

.input-with-label > input[type='text'] {
   margin: 0;
   border: none;
   width: 100%;
}

.input-with-label > .input-label {
   padding-left: 3px;
   font-size: 10px;
   border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label class="input-with-label -dollar-amount w70">
    <span class="input-label">$</span>
    <input type="text" value="0.00" />
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't setting `min-width:0` to the input and making it use all available width via `flex:1` solve the problem?

```css
.container { width: 400px; }
.w70 { width: 70px; }

.input-with-label {
   border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   background-color: #fff;
}

.input-with-label.-dollar-amount > input[type='text'] {
   text-align: right;
   font-weight: 600;
   
}

.input-with-label > input[type='text'] {
   margin: 0;
   border: none;
   min-width: 0;
   flex: 1;
}

.input-with-label > .input-label {
   padding-left: 3px;
   font-size: 10px;
   border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label class="input-with-label -dollar-amount w70">
    <span class="input-label">$</span>
    <input type="text" value="0.00" />
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: It sure does. This problem has been perplexing me all day, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I used another method

```css
.currencyinput span{
   position: relative;
}
.currencyinput input{
   padding-left:20px; 
}
.currencyinput span{
 left:15px;
 top:0
  position: absolute;
}
input{
border:1px solid lightgray;
line-height:30px;
}
```

```html
<span class="currencyinput"><span>$</span><input type="text" name="amount"></span>
```